# What is the best way to display a price with a smaller $ sign on the left using CSS?

Tags: css, html, sign

I need to display ex: $300.00, but I need the dollar sign to be displayed smaller than the number so its going to look like a trademark, but not that small.

Is there a CSS function that does that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/25m4A/

Comment: Same answer has been posted about 4 times! (subsequently downvoted, then removed). Shocking.

Comment: ..and now I have chilli up my nose! What the hell is going on.

Comment: @DamienRoche Its that kind of question, you know :)

Comment: You shouldn’t be doing this. It’s typographically and practically all wrong. A currency symbol should match the style of digits. If it does not, the font has been designed wrong, and you should use another font.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Could be something like this?

HTML:

```
<span class="dollar">300.00</span>
```

CSS:

```
.dollar:before {
    content: '$';
    font-size: somethingSmaller;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V5F94/2/) and let me know if this helps.

Comment: Great answer. But I'd suggest using em- or percent-values (e.g. 0.85em or 80%) instead of pixels (as done in the fiddle) since with em the font-size of the currency sign is relative to the font-size of the amount.

Comment: Wow didn't know about that pseudo class..
By the way if i wanted the dollar sign to display higher like a trademark, ill put, vertical-align: top; correct?
 thanks y'all.

Comment: yes, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V5F94/2/). I also edited my answer with @SVSchmidt recommendations

Comment: please, mark it as your answer it it fits your needs

Comment: This leaves essential information (currency unit) to be displayed by CSS, breaking accessibility principles.

Comment: Yes, but he wants just a $ sign on the left using CSS, this is not about accessibility principles

Answer (score 2):

But only if not empty!

```css
.currency:not(:empty):before {
        top: 0;
        content: "$";
}
```

```html
<span class="currency">10.5</span><br />
<span class="currency"></span><br />
<span class="currency">42</span><br />
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers** and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers (if there are any). [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29867380)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `<span>` element to style in-line text:

HTML:

```
<span class="currency">$</span>
<span class="price">300</span>
```

CSS:

```
.currency{

  font-size:.5em;
  vertical-align:text-top; /* resembling more the tm symbol you mentioned */

}
```

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qZRV6/1/) for convenience...

The difference from lante's answer is that this will work in much older browsers as well. For more info, see the [support for :before and :after pseudo elements](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent).

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do this would be :

HTML :

```
<div class="text">
   <span class="dollar">$</span>300
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.text {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.dollar {
    font-size:15px;
}
```

See here->http://jsfiddle.net/xMKsH/

However, if you understand pseudo-selectors well, you would be better off using this:

HTML:

```
<div class="text">300</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.dollar:before {
    content:'$';
    font-size:15px;
}
```

See here->http://jsfiddle.net/xMKsH/1/

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the :before pseudo selector

```
.amount:before {
  content: "$";
  font-size:.9em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really must do this, use

```
<small>$</small>300.00
```

and, if desired, set the size of `small` in CSS, e.g.

```
small { font-size: 75% }
```